# allure workspace issue in jenkins

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-groovy, allure

I am trying to run allure from Jenkins. I have installed the Allure Jenkins Plugin
Version2.30.2 and my current Jenkins version is Jenkins 2.346.1.

Logs:

```
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] allure
[useruk_pipeline-2_develop] $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation/allure/bin/allure generate -c -o /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/useruk_pipeline-2_develop/allure-report
allure-results does not exist
Report successfully generated to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/useruk_pipeline-2_develop/allure-report
Allure report was successfully generated.
Creating artifact for the build.
Artifact was added to the build.
[Pipeline] }
```

Code:

```
post {
    always {
        script {
            allure([
                    includeProperties: false,
                    jdk: '',
                    properties: [],
                    reportBuildPolicy: 'ALWAYS',
                    results: [[path: " ${env.WORKSPACE}/allure-results"]]
                    //results: [[path: " ${ALLURE_DIR}/allure-results"]]
                    ])
        }
        deleteDir()
    }
```

It tries to find the report under '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/useruk_pipeline-2_develop/allure-report' . Once I made a login to Jenkins box via putty and can not find the allure-results in the  workspace useruk_pipeline-2_develop.

```
jenkins@ip-xxx.xx.x.xx:~/workspace/useruk_pipeline-2_develop$ ls
Dockerfile  Jenkinsfile  behave.ini  features  requirements.txt  amt
```

But I could see the 'allure-results' in  useruk_pipeline-2_develop@2 workspace.

```
jenkins@ip-xxx.xx.x.xx:~/workspace/useruk_pipeline-2_develop@2$ ls -l | grep "all*"
total 4332
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins  282624 Aug 18 12:14 allure-results
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins     889 Aug  3 11:49 allure.py
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins    4096 Aug  3 11:49 allure_behave
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins    4096 Aug  3 11:49 allure_behave-2.5.2.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins    4096 Aug  3 11:49 allure_commons
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins    4096 Aug  3 11:49 allure_python_commons-2.5.2.dist-info
```

Could someone please assist and provide some pointers as to where should I keep my investigation towards? Also any links would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm also running into this recently and looks like the pipeline splits report and results folder into 2 different folders (one of them is appending **WORKSPACE_FOLDER@2/**.


`# find . -name '*allure*' -type d
./copy_cnsa_test_validation_test/allure-results
./copy_cnsa_test_validation_test@2/allure-report

# ls -la copy_cnsa_test_validation_test/allure-results/
total 884

# ls copy_cnsa_test_validation_test\@2/allure-report/
app.js  data  export  favicon.ico  history  index.html  plugins  styles.css  widget`

Answer (score 0):

I could eventually load up test results by manually creating `target/allure-results` folder. Looks like Jenkins infrastructure folders get created based on pipeline nodes (my case there are 6 nodes + 1 infra, latest runs agent and attempts to create allure-results, splitting results and reports into different paths).

As work around I added `target/allure-results` exactly where `allure-reports` was generated and copy folder over i.e.

- Folder structure:

```
./home/fyre/home/fyre/workspace/Jobs/Sandbox/Eduardo/copy_sw_test_validation_test@2/target/allure-results
./home/fyre/home/fyre/workspace/Jobs/Sandbox/Eduardo/copy_sw_test_validation_test@2/target/allure-report
```

- pipeline script:

```
        stage('Allure Report') {
            agent{
                node{
                    label "node-sw-slave${BUILD_NUMBER}"
                }
            }
            steps {
                ws("/home/fyre/workspace/Jobs/Sandbox/Eduardo/copy_sw_test_validation_test@2/"){
                script {
                    allure([
                        includeProperties: false,
                        jdk: '',
                        properties: [],
                        reportBuildPolicy: 'ALWAYS',
                        results: [[path: "target/allure-results"]]
                    ])              
                  }
                }
            }
        }
```

Hopefully, it will also be your Jenkins issue at your end.